# unexpected results with specific rounding mode

Tags: c, rounding, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

First of all, sorry for the bad title :/

I'm trying to reproduce a paper's results on calculating the eigenvalues of a tridiagonal symmetric matrix. I'm determining some values 'upper and lower bounds' by rounding to plus and minus infinity, respectively.

Instead of changing the rounding mode every time, I just use the 'trick': fl⁻(y) = -fl⁺(-y), where fl⁻(y) is the value of y when using the minus infinity rounding mode and fl⁺(y) is the value of y when using the rounding mode to plus infinity.
So, I have the following piece of code in C:

```
fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
first =  - (-d[i] + x);
second =  ( - (( e[i-1]*e[i-1] ) / a_inf ));
a_inf = first + second;

first = d[i] - x;
second = - ( ( e[i-1]*e[i-1] ) / a_sup );
a_sup = first + second;
```

and it works fine except for one example in which a_inf gives me the right result, but a_sup gives the wrong result, although both first and second variables seem to have the same values.

However, if I do like this:

```
  fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
  first =  - (-d[i] + x);
  second =  ( - (( e[i-1]*e[i-1] ) / a_inf ));

  fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
  first =  - (-d[i] + x);
  second =  ( - (( e[i-1]*e[i-1] ) / a_sup ));
```

I get the right results. So, if I use the trick fl⁻(y) = -fl⁺(-y), I get the right results, if I change the rounding mode and use the original expression I get wrong results. Any idea why?

In both cases, the variables first and second values are the following:

```
first  1.031250000000000e+07,  second -1.031250000000000e+07
first  1.031250000000000e+07,  second -1.031250000000000e+07
```

And the correct values for a_inf and a_sup are -1.862645149230957e-09 and +1.862645149230957e-09, respectively, but in the first case a_sup = 0, which is wrong

What I'm guessing it's happening is some kind of catastrophic cancellation, but I have no idea on how to solve it in this case...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: oops, forgot that:/, i've edited, it's C.

Comment: Please make a runtime check that the rounding mode is successfully set. I have seen it before that `fesetround` had no effect on the rounding mode. Something like `test_rounding()` in [here](http://reliablecomputing.eu/rigorousLP.c). Please turn off compiler optimization completely, it is known to mess up things.

Comment: @Ali, I'm not using any optimizations, i'm only using the flags `-std=c99 -lm` to compile. i've already tested the `fesetround`  with a simple example and with [this one](http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/cadna/Rounding_mode_Dir/Accueil.php) and I got the expected the results. I cannot compile your example, i'm getting this kind of errors undefined reference to `glp_create_prob' even after installing glpk....

Comment: @dx_mrt I meant something **like** `test_rounding()`. 0.1 is not machine representable, so if you indeed can set the rounding mode, then 1.0/10.0 rounding downwards and upwards should result in lower and upper bounds on 0.1. It the two bounds equal then setting the rounding mode failed. That's what is tested in `test_rounding()` and based on this information, you can write your own runtime test.

Comment: @dx_mrt As Chris Dodd points out too, compiler optimization can mess up things too. I would explicitly disable it, `-O0` or whatever it is your compiler uses.

Comment: @Ali well, i just declared `double x =0.1, y =10.;` and printed the result of x/y after setting the rounding mode to nearest, -inf, and +inf, i got this: 1.000000e-02. so, rounding modes not working? what's confusing me is that, if the rounding modes were not working, then the 2nd piece of code in my question shouldn't work either... i'm now compiling with -O0 and I get the same results.

Comment: @dx_mrt Assign the temporary results to variables as in my example code and check if `lower_bound<upper_bound`. If you print it, you will get 1.000000e-02 for both, it doesn't mean anything. If it works than at least you know that the rounding mode is set. Apart from that, I am out of ideas, I am sorry...

Comment: @Ali, I stored the partial results and tested 'lower_bound < upper_bound` and the result is true. so, the rounding modes are indeed working. thanks for your help :)

Comment: @dx_mrt Sorry that I cannot help you further... Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you're having is that you're only using the 'trick' to get the rounding of `first` towards -inf, and not `second`, so it is still rounded towards +inf.

The second problem is that C doesn't give you any sort of guarantee about how it does floating point computations.  In particular, the compiler is free to reorder and re-associate operations as it sees fit for performance, even if such rearrangements may change the rounding behavior of the program.  So when you say:

```
first =  - (-d[i] + x);
```

the compiler may rearrange that and do a single subtract, rather than negate, add, negate, which reverses the direction of rounding.  Now you can sometimes make things work the way you expect by disabling all optimization, but even with that, there's no guarantee.

Comment: +1 That's what I was referring to in my comment, the compiler optimization can mess up things.